# How do I implement CMFallDetectionManager and CMFallDetectionDelegate?

Tags: swift, watchos

I am trying to use `CMFallDetectionManager` to detect falls in my **watchOS** app, but I'm getting a crash when trying to simulate a fall.

Crash:

> " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid CMFallDetectionDelegate'"

I created the manager and assigned its delegate to my delegate which conforms to the `CMFallDetectionDelegate` protocol. I also implemented this function in `myDelegate` class:

```swift
func fallDetectionManager(
    _ fallDetectionManager: CMFallDetectionManager,
    didDetect event: CMFallDetectionEvent,
    completionHandler handler: @escaping () -> Void
)
```

Here is a [documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmfalldetectionmanager) for reference.

I've also added the appropriate Info.plist keys and entitlements.

Comment: When conforming to a delegate protocol that you aren't the owner of, you should never call its methods manually. The system will call the delegate methods when appropriate - the whole point of the delegate pattern is that conforming types can get notified when certain events outside of the types themselves happen. Have you added the appropriate key to the Info.plist as the docs state that you must?

Comment: Yes, I've added the appropriate keys/entitlements. I'm getting a " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid CMFallDetectionDelegate'" error when I try to simulate a fall.

Comment: Are you testing on a simulator or physical device? Is `CMFallDetectionManager.isAvailable` returning `true`? What's the `authorizationStatus` of the fall detection manager?

Comment: Testing on a simulator. CMFallDetectionManager.isAvailable is returning true and the authorizationStatus is authorized.

Comment: Could you share how you've set the delegate, where, etc. ?